# Using SetDIBitsToDevice with RGB array. Is it faster than BitBlt?

Tags: windows, graphics, bitblt

I have an array defined as:

`COLORREF* array = (COLORREF*)malloc(SCR_WIDTH * SCR_HEIGHT * sizeof(COLORREF));`

An algorithm updates this array with RGB colors continuously.

I'm just looking for a fast way to display this image on the screen, in particular `BitBlt` vs. `SetDIBitsToDevice`.

I've been successful using `BitBlt`:

```
map = CreateBitmap(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, 1, 32, (void*)array);
src = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
oldBitmap = SelectObject(src, map);
BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, src, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
SelectObject(src, oldBitmap);
DeleteDC(src);
DeleteObject(map);
```

However, I think that `SetDIBitsToDevice` would be faster since you can draw the pixels directly to the screen without the need to create a compatible DC (correct me if I'm wrong).

The problem that I'm having is that `SetDIBitsToDevice` needs these two arguments and I can't find how to obtain/create them from the RGB array:

```
const VOID       *lpvBits,
const BITMAPINFO *lpbmi,
```

Any help is appreciated. I'm also open to suggestions that could work even faster (preferably using WINGDI).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: *lpvBits* this is your *array* and in what problem declare `BITMAPINFO bi`, init it and pass ?

Comment: Thanks, that is correct. I was just missing how to define `BITMAPINFO bi`.